# What is the concept behind ...?

Tags: vectors

Could someone kindly explain the concept behind this statement 
" Vector A is perpendicular to both Vector B and Vector C. So Vector A is parallel to VectorB x Vector C "

Is there any rule like if a vector is perpendicular to two other vectors, then it is parallel to their products?

Comment: You are looking for the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Comment: Concept of vector calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a rule. You must now the [Right Hand Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule).

This rule allows you to determine which direction will the resulting vector cross product between two vectors, for a right-handed coordinate system. Right-handed coordinate systems are the most widespread and used.

This simple rule, has many practical applications, for example, determine the direction of a magnetic field according to the direction of the current that  generates it.

Comment: Link-only answers such as yours are not encouraged on this site. You should aim to make your answer self-contained, explaining the necessary concepts in your post.

Comment: @Danu Tanks so much for your suggestion!

Comment: @Tinchito ! THanks a lot ! CLearly understood

Comment: @SaravananRamesh Don't forget to check this answer as verified if you find useful! Tanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is the definition of the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) in combination with three dimensional space.

> In mathematics, the cross product or vector product is a binary operation on two vectors in three-dimensional space and is denoted by A×B (where A and B are two given vectors). It results in a vector that is perpendicular to both and therefore normal to the plane containing them. It has many applications in mathematics, physics, and engineering.

In a [three dimensional space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_dimensional_space) three vectors perpendicular to each other define the space. All vectors are triplets on the scalar values of these axis.

Comment: ! THanks a lot ! CLearly understood